# Mule4 with Open JRE 11 - Adding additional file module-info.java?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule4

I have downloaded fresh Mulesoft studio and changed configuration to point `Open JRE- 11` and compiler to point 11.

Studio version - 7.8

When I try creating the mule project it is now also adding `module-info.java` along with mule.xml files.

Wonder why it is creating module-info.java I don't used to see when i was working with 1.8 version or before.

[image]

Any Idea ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you should not run Studio itself with Java 11, only the run configurations. Studio 7.8 only supports Java 8 to start up, and you can run into unexpected behaviors using a different version: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.8-with-4.3-runtime-release-notes#software-requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 9 introduced a whole new level of encapsulation. Larger than packages, and more robust too. These are modules.

Chances are you *should* in the long term, migrate your project to use modules (for additional security, and for better code organization). However, the chances are also high that you won't want to do it right now, just because.

In that latter case, it would be reasonable to simply delete the module-info.java file. Provided you don't have any other module-info.java files in the system, and provided you run with everything on the classpath rather than module path (there's a good chance that's your default anyway) you should not have any problem.

Meanwhile, you have some homework to do, so you can decide if you will migrate to modules, and if so, how to do it.

Comment: Eggit Thanks for the good brief explanation. Clear :)